# Need to Reset Startup Drivers on Hard Drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback everyone. I think I addressed some of the questions posed and made this more understandable. Part of the issue is that I'm piecing together some of these terms for the first time from other sources, so I'm sure that's why comprehension was tough.

I'm looking for some guidance with a critical startup error. I made a mistake in trying to exchange files directly from a hard drive I typically use on my desktop to another computer using a USB-SATA III cable. I'd recently bought this new hard drive and the cable when I upgraded my system from an HDD to an SSD in order to transfer files, so that's what I used to connect to the other computer (rather than a traditional SATA cable you might find in the tower).

Basically, I plugged the hard drive into a novel computer and thought I could drag and drop specific files. I quickly realized that it seemed like it might be in some way reformatting the drive rather than simply transferring. The window showing the files showed a progress bar for something that did not look typical for file transfer but didn't have any detailed information as to what processes were occurring. I'd tried to safely eject or interrupt the process but could not, and did not want to interrupt unsafely for fear of damaging the files, especially given that the whole process only took a few seconds, which I don't think could possibly delete 300gb+ files in that time frame.  It was dumb on my part to assume I would see some sort of an error message or notice if transferring posed a problem or risk. Once I was able to, I reconnected the drive to its native desktop setup. When I booted the hard drive on its native computer, it started fine, and just about all of my files seemed to be present, but I could not open anything. I restarted the computer and immediately got an error message as the system tried to boot (Blue Screen: "NTFS File System"), and have not been able to boot since.

From what I can put together from googling help articles, people suggest I may have corrupted the startup drivers on the hard drive. When I plugged the hard drive into the new computer, as I understand it, folks said it may have been adjusting in some way to the specifications of the new computer. I'd read this can be remedied using an OS startup DVD, but my OS ownership is digital. I'd also read that after three failed starts, windows will load its automatic repair tool,  but I have not seen that initialize (which makes me a little nervous). It will just keep trying to boot, failing, restarting, and repeating. I have not tried to plug it back into the new computer for fear of making something worse. Regarding the BIOS thing, most of the articles I initially read lead me to believe that this was an issue that needed to be solved with resetting the drivers from the BIOS, but I'm not so sure that's necessarily the case. I'm currently reading about booting the system from a USB flash drive as a possible option, as well.

I back up my drives religiously, so if I need to factory reset, it's not the worst thing in the world, but I will lose a few days work and I'd prefer to avoid that. I'm using an old Dell Optiplex 7010 and a Samsung 870 EVO 500GB SSD. Of course, if these details are not enough, please let me know!

Again, largely an amateur computer enthusiast whose only real knowledge is just what I've practically had to use, so this is new territory for me. Any help or guidance towards a step-by-step would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You haven't actually told us what you did.

Comment: Along with @Tetsujin .. I must say.. not enough information.  That doesn't make you a moron.. we all have our gifts.  Please provide more information.  "Startup drivers in BIOS" makes ZERO sense to me.  We can 't help you if you can't give us enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: i find the statement "the SSD would then begin switching drivers" perplexing. It sounds like the OP may have booted a different machine using the SSD, the OS noticed the motherboard changed and then a cascade of attached devices followed. But the fact that they attached it using a usb cable makes this idea questionable.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. Sorry for the delay and thank you for the suggested edits. I hope those help, but of course, let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

I mostly figured it out! I'm able to boot normally and access all of my non-system files and programs. I'm currently stuck on regaining access to system files and programs. I'm wondering if I can maybe clone my OS to my backup hard drive, boot off of that, and then change permissions on my primary hard drive, although that might just be the same as running off of the USB boot. I outlined what steps I took to get this far. Thanks for the interest!

SOLUTION:

1.) Create a Bootable USB Flash Drive which I created using [this forum](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2376-create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-install-windows-10-a.html)

2.) Insert the USB prior to starting the computer

3.) Start the computer and press the appropriate key (for me it was F12) to get into Boot Menu (Here's a [USB Boot Tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/21756-boot-usb-drive-windows-10-pc.html))

4.) From Boot Menu, select the appropriate USB Storage Device under the Legacy heading. NOTE: I had the option to boot USB storage device under a UEFI heading, but it did not seem to connect to my hard drive when doing so.

5.) At menu displaying language options, choose "Continue"

6.) At startup window, choose "Repair My PC" in the lower left corner

7.) At repair menu, choose "Advanced Options"

8.) In Advanced Options, choose "Startup Repair". NOTE: The preferred method, [I'd seen is typically system restore](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/cannot-boot-windows-10-pc-stop-code-ntfs-file/6456fb7f-c539-4d18-9003-cca9889437b0), but that was not a viable option for me.

9.) Upon restarting, all of my files were still locked, but trying to open them prompted windows to ask me whether I wanted to "permanently grant access" to myself, which I agreed to. Doing so made the files accessible. However, my programs are all still largely locked.

10.) To correct my programs, I changed ownership of my C Drive using the 2nd bulletpoint of [this tutorial](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-apps-wont-open/) . NOTE: While this worked for all of my non-system files and programs, I received error messages for windows files. I tried to restart the computer using the USB boot to see if I can change permissions for system files when the system is running off of the USB, but that did not work, so this is where I'm currently stuck.

Hope this is helpful for others !